# joined tables lost 'id' attribute

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to join two tables to be able to relate the corresponding 'theme' to a 'topic'. The join seems to work, but the template gives this error when rendering:

> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'sqlalchemy.util._collections.result
>   object' has no attribute 'id'

How can I address Topic.id after joining the tables?

*models*

```
class Topic(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    topic_name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    opinions = db.relationship(Opinion, backref='topic')
    theme_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('theme.id'))

class Theme(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    theme_name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    topics = db.relationship(Topic, backref='theme')
```

*view*

```
@main.route('/topics', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def topics():
    topics = db.session.query(Topic, Theme).join(Theme).order_by(Theme.theme_name).all()
    themes = Theme.query
    form = TopicForm()
    form.theme.choices = [(t.id, t.theme_name) for t in Theme.query.order_by('theme_name')]
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        topic = Topic(topic_name=form.topic_name.data,
                    theme_id=form.theme.data)
        db.session.add(topic)
    return render_template('topics.html', topics=topics, themes=themes, form=form)
```

*html jinja2 template*

```
<table class="table table-hover parties">
        <thead><tr><th>Theme</th><th>#</th><th>Name</th><th>Delete</th></tr></thead>
        {% for topic in topics %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#">{{ topic.theme_id }}</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">{{ topic.id }}</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">{{ topic.topic_name }}<span class="badge">0</span></a></td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" href="{{ url_for('main.delete_topic', id=topic.id) }}" role="button">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alter your query to be:

```
topics = db.session.query(Topic).join(Theme).order_by(Theme.theme_name).all()
```

Using `query(Topic)` indicates we are interested in getting `Topic` values back.  In contrast, your current implementation uses `query(Topic, Theme)` which indicates you are interested in getting tuples of `(Topic, Theme)`.

Comment: Thanks, that was a quick solution. Clear difference between the two implementations.